# How to make article alias of subcategories as 1 level?

Tags: joomla-2.5, alias

In a joomla website I have a category and its 2 different subcategories like

**News**

1. __Subcategory1
2. __Subcategory2
3. __Subcategory2

My news catagory used News Show Pro GK4 ver. 3.3.6 plugin

If I added a articles to a subcategory the url is like

www.mysite.com/news/Subcategory1/article1.html

If I added a articles to the main category the url is like

www.mysite.com/news/menuid-news/article1.html

How can I make the urls like www.mysite.com/news/article1.html for all articles in catagories and subcatagories ??

Anyone can help me........

Answer (score 4):

The only way I know to remove menu or category IDs from the urls is to either override the router system (not fun) or use a SEF component like sh404Sef (there a several others, I just used this one as an example). It lets you fully control the alias/urls for everything in your site.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the subcategory name from the url ?

Comment: Same way, use a SEF extension.

Comment: any other solution ?

Comment: The only other way without an extension is to make a menu item for every single article. Menu items give articles a real url "alias" and the url takes on the menu structure without putting IDs in it.